# How can i add CheckBox in the list view items?

Tags: android, listview

In My application i am using two list view's in one activity, one for only items and one list view i am have add check box in every row. 
My requirement is in below list view if item is checked i have to display on text view in the main activity if not have to display another activity .

i was not used ListActivity for this i just created from Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60px">                
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60px">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

above list view for only items for below list view i have to add check box. how can i achieve this.

my activity is..

```
public  class Settings extends Activity   {    
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.settings); 

   ListView list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
   ListView list2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);

   list2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,      
     android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, Display));

   list2.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
   list2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) {

      }
 });    
   list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, Categories));

   list1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
   list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) {

      }
 });                
}
    static final String[] Categories = new String[] {
    "Alarm1","Alarm2","Alarm3","Alarm4","Alarm5"
    };
    static final String[] Display = new String[] {
    "24 Hours","Display Seconds"
    };   
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.provider, null);
            TextView location = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.description);
            checkBoxImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_id);
            Provider p = (Provider) getItem(position);
            location.setText(p.Description + " - " + p.Location);
            return convertView;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#overview_listview) is the Complete Tutorial how you can include CheckBox in a List. Its the Best Tutorial Regarding the `ListView` & `ListActivity`.

Comment: nice tutorials , than you... from this tutorial i got much information

Comment: Welcome, yeah its a very nice Tutorial mostly covering many things about ListView and ListActivity.